# Choice between two expressions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I need to express $ \frac{1}{T} $ from $ \varphi = \frac{\rho}{T} $. It appears that there are two ways of doing that

$$\frac{1}{T} = \frac{\varphi}{\rho}$$

or

$$\frac{1}{T} = \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial \rho}$$

Is there a reason why I should prefer the latter rather than the former way of expressing $ \frac{1}{T} $? The problem is that I need to choose one of the two ways, in order to substitute in

$$\frac{1}{T} = -\frac{1}{\beta \nu}ln \frac{\rho}{\alpha \nu^3}$$

and the choice would make a difference in the final calculation of $ \varphi $.

Comment: What is $T$? Is it a function? Is it a constant?

Comment: If $\partial$ is a constant, then they're the same. However, probably $\partial$ represents a partial derivative, which is a mathematical operation that changes its argument significantly—in this case the second expression is definitely incorrect.

Comment: @Kman3, $T$ is a constant.

Comment: @Greg Martin, $\partial$ is a partial derivative. Can you elaborate, please. Thanks.

Comment: @ganzewoort What Greg Martin meant is that, if $\varphi$ is a function of variables including $\rho$, $\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial\rho}$ means that you are taking the instantaneous rate of change of $\varphi$ with respect to $\rho$ while holding the other variables constant. 

Some characters are already 'taken', for instance, $e$ is the Euler's number, $i$ is the imaginary units, etc.

Comment: @soupless, will it help if instead of $\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial \rho}$, the derivative is written explicitly as $\frac{\partial \varphi (\rho(\nu), \nu)}{\partial \rho}$? Why is it wrong, then, if $\varphi = \frac{\rho}{T}$, to have $\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial \rho} = \frac{1}{T}$?

Comment: Before that, are you solving a PDE?

Comment: @soupless, $\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial \rho} = \frac{1}{T}$ comes about as a result of solving an optimization problem, whereby, given $S = v \int\limits_0^\infty \varphi(\rho(\nu), \nu) d\nu$, said $S$ will have a maximum $\delta \int\limits_0^\infty \varphi d\nu = 0$ if $\delta \int\limits_0^\infty \rho d\nu = 0$. This leads to $\int\limits_0^\infty \left( \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial \rho} -\lambda \right) \delta \rho d\nu = 0$, which proves that $\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial \rho}$ is independent of $\nu$.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. In that case, you should use the second one because it is what it is, and you can't treat $\partial$ as a constant that you can cancel on both numerator and denominator. But try asking other people. (Also, you can use `\ln` instead of `ln` to make $\ln$ upright.)

Comment: The first relation is unconditionally true, however. Thus, I still don't understand why the $\frac{1}{T}$ obtained in those two ways gives different results for $\varphi$ when substituted in $\frac{1}{T} = -\frac{1}{\beta \nu} \ln \frac{\rho}{\alpha \nu^3}$. The reason may be due to some subtlety in the optimization solution.